# How to create a form on a new page?

Tags: forms, nodes

I'm new to Drupal. What I'd like to do is create a form on a new page, having full control over the css/html of the form, and post the form to PHP for processing. The PHP should do some custom things to the form data, dump some stuff to the DB, return some stuff from the DB, and either redirect to a new page or return an error. No need to go into details about the PHP/DB stuff - just need to figure out how to go about creating a new page, and where to post the form to for processing. Should be able to figure everything else out from there!

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. This is not the way Drupal actually works. You cannot code an HTML form into a content type. Would you edit and explain what you actually trying to achieve with this form?

Comment: Hi Елин Й., I've tried to explain my general goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a form on a page you need to use Drupal's [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7). It seems a bit complex at the first sight, but it isn't as it seems.

The steps you need to follow:

1. [Create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/1074360)
2. Implement [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in your module and set a path for your page which should render the form.
3. A form builder function that builds a form using the Form API.

An Example for hook_menu() implementation:

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {
  $items['some/path'] = array(
    'title' => 'My page title',
    'description' => 'An example page',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('YOURMODULE_example_form'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

This code registers a paths as http://example.com/some/path and calls [drupal_get_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function, which gets a form with the given id, which in this example is `YOURMODULE_example_form`.

An example for the form builder function:

```
function YOURMODULE_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['some_text_field'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Enter some text'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Send form'),
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: In terms of rendering the form - the form needs to have very custom HTML & CSS. Is this possible?

Comment: Indeed you may have to implement some theme functions as well to get an exact HTML structure of the form. But the actual HTML of Drupal forms are not known as the cleanest ones.